# cannot read property style of undefined error

Tags: javascript

I am getting a cannot read property style of undefined error, and I am not sure why it is returning undefined. I am attempting to have my elements change color on mouseover. The code I am using is:

```
var icons = document.getElementsByClassName('icon');
for ( i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
    console.log(icons.length);
    icons[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        console.log(icons[i]);
        icons[i].style.color = "#00FF00";
    });
};
```

EDIT: I was able to get it to work by doing the following:

```
var icon = document.getElementsByClassName('icon');

function getValue(i) {
    return (i);
}

for (var i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) {
    icon[i] = getValue(i);
    icon[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    });
    icon[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    });
}
```

Comment: Wrap the body of `for` in closure to keep separate copy of `i`.

Comment: @Tushar Or use event delegation like a normal human being. ;)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Or use CSS `:hover` like designer :)

Comment: @Tushar Thought about that, wouldn't match the functionality described by the code (i.e. color doesn't wear off after unhovering).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Right. Lets hope OP understands what's wrong in the code and how this issue can be solved.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - `event delegation` sounds like a jQueery thing

Comment: @JaromandaX event delegation is definitely not a jQuery thing. jQuery has event delegation, as does native DOM.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - indeed, simple to write in jQueery, a little verbose in plain javascript for all but the simplest cases

Comment: @JaromandaX Not really, it's a 6 line function to mock it up. `function on(selector, callback) { ... }`

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - I'll take your word for it :p - once I ever find a use for it, I'll probably realise how useful it is

Comment: @JaromandaX https://jsfiddle.net/fyvv7Lna/ There, this works for most of what most people need. But I don't like having to deal with DOM directly in a web application anyway. I either abstract it away to my own controls, or I use a library like React to do it for me.

Comment: that indexOf should be `>= 0` surely :p (or `~[].indexOf.call...` FTW)

Comment: I solved it. I edited the above with the answer